# Propagating c++ exception to cython - python exception

Tags: c++, python, exception, try-catch, cython

I have a problem with Cython 0.17.1

My function throws a `std::runtime_error` if a file doesn't exist, I'd like to propagate this exception in some manner to my Cython code.

```
void loadFile(const string &filename)
{
    // some code, if filename doesn't exists 
    throw std::runtime_error( std::string("File doesn't exists" ) );
}
```

and from Cython after the right wrapping of the function:

```
try:
    loadFile(myfilename)
except RuntimeError:
    print "Can't load file"
```

but this exception is always ignored, how can I catch c++ exceptions from Python?

Comment: Did you use [`except +`](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#exceptions) in your `cdef`?

Comment: yes, probably I should post some more code...

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the exception is thrown on the C++ side? You could also try replacing `except RuntimeError` with `except Exception, e` and print `e` to see if maybe some other Python exception is raised.

Answer (score 8):

Are you declaring the exception handling with the extern? You should read about C++ exception handling: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#exceptions

Basically, you need to do something like the following:

```
cdef extern from "some_file.h":
    cdef int foo() except +
```

Comment: Yes my function has the "except +" declared but I'm still unable to detect the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your function as `except +`, see http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#exceptions